# 14-2 and 14-3 into one box

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, multiway-switch

In my basement wiring diagram - in Box #1  -- I have a 14-2 cable from the panel and a 14-3 cable terminating a 3 way switch (6 & 7) from the same circuit.

Is this ok, normal, against code, dangerous?

Is there a better way to wire my basement layout off of one circuit with two 3 way switches?

Thank you.

[image: Basement wiring diagram]

Answer (score 1):

No.  You've created a wiring loop.

There's a fundamental rule that currents must be equal in each cable or conduit.   The way you accomplish that is by laying your cables in a **tree topology**. Any number of branches, but branches can't ever rejoin each other.

You need to air-gap *either* the two things in box 5, *or* air-gap the two switches in box 1.

Stick a partition inside the box and no wires cross it. Partitions are mandatory for separating low-voltage wiring from mains wiring in the same junction box.   Truth be told they're not *physically* mandatory in this case, but the idea of total separation is mandatory.

In fact, I really do recommend physical separation because if you don't, it's a matter of time before some gooberhead decides he wants to put a smart switch in a 3-way remote location, so he crosses the partition to poach a neutral wire.  And now you have an illegal loop.

Also remember you can take power to the lamps first and double-back to the switches in a "switch loop", but if you do, Code requires you to use 14/3 in the switch loop. That will leave a spare wire, which is future neutral for use by smart switches.

Comment: It looks like the 6-7 cable has a neutral in it, so yeah -- definitely recommend going with the partition here to avoid looped neutrals with 2 separate neutrals in the box.

Comment: Could I do it a better way by using smart switches for the 3-way's instead?  Is there a better way to wire what I have, or just go with the physical partition?

Comment: @Derek the partition will suffice, but a wireless smartswitch like Insteon would be less wire and more elegant.